# Can i get the scroll event from handsontable

Tags: angular, handsontable

currently i am using your handsontable product in an angular project. But I have got a problem with the scroll detection. I need to detect and catch the scroll event on a table. Is it possible? (onScroll on a normal html element). And also the vice versa that i want to set the scroll dynamically something like (element.scrollTop += 10)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put a div around your table or tbody with the height, width and scroll. Then inside that div put:

```
(scroll)="onScroll($event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
jQuery(
    function($) {
        $('#flux').bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                alert('end reached');
            }
        })
    }
);
```